# How to enable Timer 2 on PIC18?

Tags: c, timer, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I want to enable timer2 to be able to use pulse width modulation. I am using [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778e.pdf) with internal 8MHz oscillator. I have minimum knowledge about PIC programming, so I want to know what else is missing in my code to enable the timer.

```
#define TMR2_IF          PIR1bits.TMR2IF 
#define TMR2_IE          PIE1bits.TMR2IE
#define TMR2_IP          IPR1bits.TMR2IP
#define TMR2_CON         T2CON
```

Let's say this is my main code for now

```
void main()
{
     TMR2_CON = 0b00000100 | CLOCK_DIVIDER_SETTING; // CLOCK_DIVIDER_SETTING = 4

     TMR2_IF = 0;
     TMR2_IE = 1;
     TMR2_IP = 1;

 while(1);

}
```

The rest of the code that I don't yet know where to place it.

```
if(TMR2_IF)
    {

        printf("\r\nHello");

        if(TMR2_IE)

         {
            TMR2_IF = 0;
         }

   }
```

**Do I need an Interrupt Service Routine?** If Yes, how do I add it? Remember my goal is to use the PWM which I still did not get there yet, but for now I want to make sure the settings for timer2 are correct.

**What else is missing?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am still stuck with timer2

Comment: Any further suggestions ?

Comment: Take a look at embeddedcodesource.com from Microchip. There you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks, it seems helpful.

Answer (score 0):

change the `while(1);`

to

```
while(1)
{

if(TMR2_IF)
    {

        printf("\r\nHello");

        if(TMR2_IE)

         {
            TMR2_IF = 0;
         }

   }
}
```

Comment: this prints out very fast, why is that?

Comment: I noticed changing the Prescaler and Postscale does not really effect it greatly. I still see the statement being printed probably every 200ms